# Does anyone have the source code of content monster web part?

Tags: sharepoint, cqwp

the archived link on MSDN seems to broken and no longer works. the link on the author's blog points to MSDN too, I've already tried quiet a few blogs but all point to the same MSDN archive.
thanks.